# Dynamically added element not showing in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to dynamically add an element to a div. However this element is not shown in the view. If I try to inspect the element the new paragraph is not there(this seems to be the normal behavior of inspect element from what I've read). However I go in the console and select the element through javascript and all the new elements are there but can't be seen.

```
<div id="moving_to_2perf">
DA
<p> paragraph</p>
</div>

<style type="text/css">  
#moving_to_2perf{
  color: red;
};     
</style>  

<script type='text/javascript'>

  function getCookie(cname) {
      var name = cname + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
              c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
              return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
          }
      }
      return "";
  }

  function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
  }

  $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log('salut1');
    insert_text();
  });

  cookie = getCookie('2parale_to_2performant_cokie');
  if (!cookie) {
    insert_text2();
  };

  function insert_text(){
    console.log('salut2');
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
    para.appendChild(node);

    var element = document.getElementById("moving_to_2perf");
    element.appendChild(para);
  };

  function insert_text2(){
    console.log('salut3');
    $("#moving_to_2perf").html("Hello World");
    $("#moving_to_2perf").append('<p id="testp"> TEST </p>');

    console.log($('#testp').position());
    console.log($('#testp').offset());
  };


</script>
```

The elements are there, but I can't see them. I can see the original elements however. Help ?

Comment: I can see the new elements. https://jsfiddle.net/x647gtc8/

Comment: I think it's because of something rails does, i don't know ... it doesn't update the div so I can see the text added by javascript